ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests' after pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
I installed Office365-REST-Python-Client to access SharePoint in Python. I want to run
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
pip install "git+https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client.git@master"
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url 

But I get the error message saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'." I thought Office365-REST-Python-Client comes with 'tests', but apparently it's not so I tried to run
pip install tests

But it's still not helpful. There is a similar question posted (Cannot find package "tests")
and there is a solution provided in the comment, but I could not understand copying the package from Git so asking it here again. How can I use the package 'tests' in Python? Thank you.
[Code to run][1]
